# How do I get an API Username, Password, & signature from PayPal to use in a third party plugin

Tags: api, paypal, signature

I ended up here from paypal because I can only find programming info to add apps to paypal or something to that effect. I am trying to get info from paypal to plug into WP-Client so I can invoice clients through my website via Paypal. Every time I ask this question on Paypals site they send me to the developers reference which I don't understand nor need. The programming is done, I just want access to my paypal account through my plugin which asks for the API username, Password, and Signature.

Comment: You may want to elaborate further including exact examples of your issue.  Examples will help us better gauge where your issue may exists.

Answer (score 3):

You can [login to this tool](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run) to obtain your API credentials quickly and easily.

Answer (score 0):

This info can be obtained in your Paypal profile after you login to your PayPal account.

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/apicertificates

Hope this helps.